# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar de ramas en Git?

Tags: git

No puedo ver la lista de las ramas que he creado, utilizo `git branch` pero nada, tampoco puedo cambiar de rama, probe con `git switch master`, `git branch master`y `git checkout master` y tampoco obtengo resultados.

Solamente puedo crear nuevas ramas y acceder a ellas con `git checkout -b "nuevaRama"`

Comment: Sin los resultados de dichos comandos, imposible decir nada.

Comment: Me parece que no estás en el directorio del repo, o estás en un repo equivocado.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando los comandos de Git no funcionan, generalmente no estas en un directorio "controlado" por Git, esto ocurre por ejemplo al clonar un proyecto en la ubicación actual, todavía queda movernos al nuevo directorio para poder usar los comandos de trabajo habituales de Git.

Para saber si puedes trabajar con Git en el directorio actual puedes lanzar:

```
git status
```

Si estas fuera de un directorio Git aparece un mensaje como el siguiente:

> fatal: no es un repositorio git (ni ninguno de los directorios superiores): .git

Si estas en la ruta correcta, es decir vas a empezar a usar Git en el directorio actual debes inicial el repositorio:

```
git init
```

Si después de esto tratas de listar las ramas no aparece nada, aunque estas en la rama *master* (o lo estabas almenos con las versiones de Git de hace unos meses, ahora no se, en Github, por ejemplo, los repos desde hace unos meses crean la rama *main*).

Bueno, si compruebas el estado:

```
git status
```

Te indica la rama y algún detalle más:

> En la rama master

> No hay commits todavía

> no hay nada para confirmar (crea/copia archivos y usa "git add" para hacerles seguimiento)
> Con independencia de esto si puedes crear nuevas ramas, yo uso el comando:

```
git checkout -b nueva-rama
```

*La creo y me muevo a ella.*

Aunque ahora existen dos ramas, si trato de listar, sigue sin aparecer nada:

```
git branch
```

De nuevo, comprobar el estado:

```
git status
```

y la salida:

> En la rama nueva-rama

> No hay commits todavía

> no hay nada para confirmar (crea/copia archivos y usa "git add" para hacerles seguimiento)

Puedes hacer un *commit* y volver a listar las ramas:

```
git branch
```

Y ahora sí, te aparece la rama actual:

> - develop

Si tratas de moverte a la rama "master", resulta que no existe:

```
git checkout master
```

> error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Ahora puedes crearla y moverte a ella, volver a *develop* y volver a listar:

```
git branch
```

Veras que existen tanto *master* como *develop*...

---

Aunque *master* es la rama inicial de un repositorio Git,
si este esta vacío, creamos y nos movemos a otra rama, deja de existir...
una rama sin contenido solo existe mientras estamos en ella.

Si tratas de crear ramas, moverte entre ellas, ver el estado del repositorio, etc. y no estas en un directorio *controlado* por Git, tendrás un mensaje de error al respecto.